# So am I or So do I

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I love going on picnics.  What should be the answer ? : 
- So am I . 
or 
- So do I .

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112951/uninterested-me-too-or-me-either/112953#112953 and its dupe: [Is it correct to use “me too” and “I too”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/is-it-correct-to-use-me-too-and-i-too)

Answer (score 1):

It's "So do I".

We would use BE (*am, are, is*)  only if Be were the main verb in the first sentence:

*I **am** going on a picnic.* 
*So **am** I.*

*I **am** a teacher.*
*So **am** I.*

*I **love** picnics.*
*So **do** I.*

*I **love** going on picnics.* 
*So **do** I*

Comment: "Be" can be both an auxiliary and a main verb, in both cases we say "So am I."

Comment: Good point. I've added an example to my response.

Comment: When BE is the sole verb in a sentence it can hardly be an auxiliary.

Comment: tunny: in *"Is he a teacher?"*, would you consider the verb "Is" an auxiliary verb? (cc: @snailboat )

Comment: No. "The verb BE is a main verb (with a copular function) in: "Ann is a happy girl" Quirk et al, 'A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language', 1985.129) Auxiliary verbs "regularly accompany full verbs" (The Oxford Companion to the English Verb".

Comment: @tunny Even though "Is" had undergone subject-auxiliary inversion? Subject-auxiliary inversion uses an auxiliary verb, doesn't it?

Comment: Until about 1400, auxiliary DO was not used in questions. The standard way of forming questions was S-V inversion. In modern English, the interrogative of lexical verbs is formed with DO, and of modals still by inversion. The three primary auxiliary verbs, HAVE, BE and DO function both as lexical and auxiliary verbs. As a lexical verb, DO requires auxiliary DO for questions; most people use auxiliary DO with HAVE, though inversion is still used by some speakers of BrE; only inversion is used with BE.

Comment: But the question is about subject-auxiliary inversion in today's standard English. Is there subject-auxiliary inversion in *"Is he a teacher?",* and if so, then wouldn't that make the verb "Is" be an auxiliary verb?

Comment: Auxiliary verbs accompany full verbs. That is my understanding of auxiliary verbs. If you wish to think otherwise, fine.

Comment: @tunny F.Y.I. You'll need to insert a "@" and userid of the person you are responding to, for them to get a ding when you are addressing them with a comment. I don't have to do that here, under your post, because you will automatically get dinged because this is your post that we are commenting on.

Comment: Auxiliary verbs have certain properties, well the core members do, and one of those properties is subject-auxiliary inversion. In today's standard English, lexical verbs (non-auxiliary verbs) do not, in general, participate in subject-auxiliary inversion. Another property that differentiates an auxiliary verb from a lexical verb is negation: auxiliary verbs can support negation, but lexical verbs require the assistance of an auxiliary verb. E.g. *"Isn't he a teacher?"* and *"He is not a teacher"* are good sentences, but not so for *"Likes he not ice cream?"* and *"He likes not ice cream"*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18273/discussion-between-tunny-and-f-e).

Comment: In general, I don't do "chat". I can easily delete my comments here under a post, but cannot do that in chat.  Chat also has other limitations.

Answer (score 1):

The first person is talking about

> **doing** *something*
>
> I want to get some dinner.
>   I would like to go home.
>   I run every morning.

so your answer would be

> So **do** I!

If the first person was talking about

> *be*-ing *something*
>
> I **am** late for the flight!
>   I **am** hungry!
>   I **am** bored in class.

your answer would be

> So **am** I!

Answer (score 0):

So do I.  The word Love is used here. If be verb was used in original sentence, then the answer would be so am I.

Comment: A confusing answer. This needs some serious formatting and grammar tweaks.